# Centering CSS Masonry Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, masonry

I made a simple masonry layout using css grid.

My requirement is that I wanted a maximum of 8 columns and make it responsive with the screen size.

Everything works great until I have >=8 bricks in the "masonry". As the number of bricks become <8, I want the 'n' columns to be centered in the 'masonry'.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="masonry">
        <div class="brick">
            <p class="subheading-text">Automobiles</p>
            <img class="content-img" src="https://www.otgads.com/site_contents/image_Ad/235/1672659803.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img class="content-img" src="https://www.otgads.com/site_contents/image_Ad/233/download (2).jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <p class="subheading-text">Badhai</p>
            <img class="content-img" src="https://www.otgads.com/site_contents/image_Ad/223/advertisement(2).jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <p class="content-text"><strong>Lorem</strong> Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop </p> 
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <p class="subheading-text">Business</p>
            <p class="content-text"><strong>WANTED</strong> Investor/Partner Rs.3.5 Cr for our Packaging Material mfg Unit Nr. Mumbai 7021629703 9821009496</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <p class="subheading-text">Education</p>
            <p class="content-text"><strong>Lorem</strong> Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.masonry {
  --masonry-gap: 15px;
  --masonry-brick-width: 200px;
  column-gap: var(--masonry-gap);
  column-fill: initial;
  column-width: var(--masonry-brick-width);
  max-width: 1740px;
}

.masonry > * {
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: var(--masonry-gap);
}

@supports (grid-template-rows: masonry) {
  .masonry {
    display: grid;
    gap: var(--masonry-gap);
    grid-template-rows: masonry;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(
      auto-fill,
      minmax(var(--masonry-brick-width), 1fr)
    );
    align-tracks: stretch;
  }

  .masonry > * {
    margin-bottom: initial;
  }
}

/* some styling not important */
.masonry {
  padding: 8px;
}

.content-text {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.content-text:hover {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 19px 43px;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1px, 0px);
}

.heading-text {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ca4040;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.subheading-text {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #404eca;
  border: 3px solid #404eca;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.content-img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.content-img:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 19px 43px;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1px, 0px);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to center the contents in the 'masonry' div but they were always left aligned if the number of bricks were <8 (max 8 as I have fixed the max-width of 'masonry' div to 1740px)

Answer (score 0):

```
.masonry {
  --masonry-gap: 15px;
  --masonry-brick-width: 200px;
  column-gap: var(--masonry-gap);
  column-fill: initial;
  column-width: var(--masonry-brick-width);
  max-width: 1740px;
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--masonry-gap);
  grid-template-rows: masonry;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--masonry-brick-width), 1fr));
  align-items: center; /* added to center the columns */
  align-tracks: stretch;
}
```